# What's the term for a person who can/will do anything for money?

Tags: word-request

Is there any term that describes a person who can/will do anything for money? Help me filling the blank.

> *Do you know what did Tom do? He sold secret information of his own country 
>   Yeah, possible! He's a/an **______________________**. He will/can do anything for money.*

Comment: I'm not sure these words are what you're looking for, so I'll post them here as a comment. Unlike other answerers, for me, your blank to fill evokes the sense of dishonesty instead of "easy to buy". So my likely choice is probably: a *crook*. I looked up for their synonyms, and I think these could also work: *knave*, *rogue*, and *rascal*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You got it! It's certainly in a negative sense! But then *crook* is different and so your other synonyms. They denote more dishonesty than his hunger toward wealth.

Comment: My guess is your original thought was closer to *"He could do anything ..."* than to *"He'll do anything ..."*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. This is what I'm thinking after editing. I'm now confused. But don't you think *will* is stronger than *can* here? I just want to emphasize that if someone is finding money in something, he'll do it forgetting ethics, principles, morale, family, or whatsoever. Okay, kept both to emphasize it better.

Comment: I believe that Indian and Thai languages are not too far apart, so I believe that I could guess what you thought of at some level (I wasn't absolutely sure, though; I mean, I think I can't be that sure). This is exactly the case where *could* is permissible but *can* isn't. (Using *will* is fine, but I believe that it would be a little different from what you originally thought of.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Well this is getting interesting. A money-grubber **will** do anything talks about the surety in the future that he'll do any possible misdoing for money whereas a money-grubber **can** do denotes that he'll put **every** effort possible (he'll extend his capability) to get money. And yes, Cambridge's definition of *money-grubber* is what I'm looking for. Esoteric got it!

Comment: This is difficult to explain (and many of our ELL fellows are struggling with this). I also think that my intuition on these modal verb usages is still far from complete. However, for this *can* vs *could* (in *could do anything*), I think if I want to put it simply, it might be something like this. Using *He can ...* expresses the fact that that *he* can do such a thing. Using *He could ...* expresses that you think (or guess) that it's possible for that *he* to do such a thing. The difference is really small, but it's there, and it's enough to prohibit the *can* in your sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nouns:

- *Grafter*. [1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/graft), [2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/graft) (def. 2 in both cases). Someone who engages in and benefits from graft, which is the abuse of one's position of (often political) power or authority for the purpose of gaining money by illegal or immoral means. It would not be appropriate to call a filing clerk who copied and sold classified papers a *grafter*.
- *Money-grubber*. [1](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/money-grubbing?q=money+grubber), [2](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moneygrubbing). Someone who's solely or overly interested in money and will take almost any opportunity to acquire more. The term focuses more on the desire for money than the willingness to do anything to get it, though someone *money grubbing* would be willing to do many things (but not necessarily *anything*) others aren't in order to get paid.

I do know of a word that fits exactly what you're after, but it's extremely rude and vulgar. See below if you're interested.

> *Whore*. Typically this means *prostitute*, but modern and informal usage has expanded it to refer to someone who will do anything, especially immoral or degrading acts, for money or gain. Synonyms (*prostitute*, *hooker*, etc.) don't carry this expanded meaning.

Adjectives:

- *[Venal](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/venal)*. The right meaning, but wrong type of word. The noun form, *venality*, is *the quality of being venal*, not a person who is *venal*.
- *For sale*. Informal, meaning *venal* or *able to be bought or bribed*. "I can't believe Judge Watkins is presiding over the mob trial; everyone knows he's *for sale*." "His access to the credit card database is *for sale* to the highest bidder."

Comment: Ah, I suggest an edit putting definition of money-grubber from Cambridge. It's even closer to what I'm thinking. :)  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/money-grubbing?q=money+grubber

Comment: I'm not sure I'd characterize _whore_ as "extremely rude and vulgar," although I agree that it should be used with caution. I'd avoid using it around kids or in a professional environment.

Comment: @J.R. Agreed, but I figured I'd err on the side of caution, just in case there are cross cultural issues I'm ignorant of. And as always, exactly how rude it is depends on the context and delivery.

Comment: @J.R.  if this word is descriptive and accurate, why would you want to insulate children from it?

Comment: @Gusdor - I can think of quite a few descriptive words I wouldn't use around young children - but that's a question for [parenting.SE].

Answer (score 6):

**Mercenary** as an adjective or noun could provide a suitable description for such a person.

> ## mercenary
>
> #### adjective
>
> **1.** primarily concerned with making money at the expense of ethics
>
> #### noun
>
> **1.1** A person primarily concerned with material reward at the expense of ethics
>
> <sub>Source: [ODO Definition of “mercenary”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mercenary)</sub>

Comment: True, but please note that this is indeed the *adjective* form of mercenary, as you say, and cannot fill in the blank in Maulik's sentence. Mercenary as a *noun* is most likely to be understood as "a soldier-for-hire".

Comment: Agree with Wendikidd. Though it is a noun as well, the use of this word in the sense I'm asking is rare. If you *label* anyone *mercenary* the first thing conveyed is a *hired solider*.

Answer (score 2):

He's a **[sell out](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sell-out)** (sense 3).　He can do anything for money.

Comment: *Sell-out* is leaning more toward *betrayal* I think.

Comment: @MaulikV Doing something only for money usually has some kind of betrayal on the flip side.

Comment: Not at all. An unmarried whore would sleep with an unmarried man for the sake of money. Is she betraying? Certainly not. Pardon my language though. But this is what I could think quickly about.

Comment: @MaulikV - _sell-out_ may not be the best suggestion here, but it's a valid one. It's a term often used when someone abandons their principles for the sake of personal gain. That gain need not be money, but it could be. It certainly fits in your blank: _Tom sold secrets? He's such a **sell-out**; he will do anything for money._ See also the definitions at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sellout).

Comment: @MaulikV Your example is terrible. You're perpetuating a fantasy that a sex worker will do _anything_ for money.

Answer (score 0):

In America/Chicago, my country/city, we use either **Gold-Digger** or the term **easy**.

Ellen is such a *gold digger*, she just after Jeff's money.

Jackie is pretty *easy*, she'll do anything for a bit of attention

Hope this helps - Mack