# What is a term for the man who is ready to do everything to get money?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

I am in search for a term that describes someone doing anything to get money. For this, he or she may compromise his or her moral or ethics. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to ELL. Don't accept the answer immediately. Let others come up with their thoughts. Anyway thanks. You can always 'deselect' this answer and select the other one if you find it better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the term for a person who can/will do anything for money?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26565/3281)

Answer (score 7):

The closest term I can think for this person is

> [mercenary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mercenary) - *interested only in the money or other personal advantages that you can get from something*

But then, it serves as an *adjective*.

Note that when the term is used **[as a noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mercenary_1)**, it describes *a soldier who will fight for any country or group that offers payment*.

---

I got **the better option:**

> *[venal](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/venal)* -*prepared to do dishonest or immoral things in return for money*

Comment: Doesn't greedy work?

Comment: *Greedy* is a person who *wants* more money. Not necessarily leaving his *moral/ethics* as you describe!

Comment: @MaulikV A greedy person is usually willing to do anything, ethical or not, for what they want. If I was greedy for up votes, I would post "greedy" as an answer even though it wasn't my idea. The connotation fits well.

Comment: True but *greedy* could be applied to anything, not necessarily money. What say? @D_Bester On the other hand, *venal* and *mercenary* are *meant* to associate with money!

Comment: Greedy is a more common word. I'm American (USA) but I didn't know the definition of venal. I completely agree that both of your words fit better than greedy.

Answer (score 5):

A **profiteer** tries to make abnormally high profits and is usually seen as someone with questionable scruples

An unmarried woman is a *gold digger* if she is trying to 'trap' a wealthy man into marriage, mostly interested in his wealth. This term, and practice(?) is a bit dated.

*Ruthless* can be used for someone who will stop at nothing, although he doesn't necessarily operate out of a fiduciary motive.

A *tycoon* is someone who has made it big in money, and we know such a person can never have enough. You could use *ruthless tycoon*. Or just - capitalist. ;)

**Mercenary** is a good word. I would use that before I used venal. ;)

A *scrooge* is, well, a scrooge, someone who hoards money and is loath to depart with it.

A *shylock* is a person of irreputable character (literally) who lends money for an extremely high return.

An *extortionist* will use criminal methods to get money out of people.

*Money grubber* is excellent for one whose main interest in life is acquiring wealth.

Comment: You forgot _banker_ or, more accurately, _investment banker_. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "acquisitive" or "avaricious", the latter is more toxic sounding.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on your context. If you're referring to someone who would rip out their own teeth on command just to get some extra money, then you'd simply call such a person "desperate."

If you're talking about someone who, in business practices of any kind, will do anything they can get away with for the sake of extra profit, you'd say they are "[cut-throat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cutthroat)".

> (of a competitive situation or activity) fierce and intense; involving
>   the use of ruthless measures.  
>   "cutthroat competition led to a lot of bankruptcies"
>   synonyms:   ruthless, merciless, fierce, intense, aggressive,
>   dog-eat-dog; vulgar slang: ass-kicking 
>   "cutthroat competition between rival firms"

In informal speech, you would hear such a person being described as someone willing to part with the most precious and priceless of things for the smallest of gains. It's typical to hear/say something like "He/she would sell INSERT_SOMETHING_PRICELESS just to make a buck." Some examples:

> He'd sell his own mother for a buck.
>
> He'd sell his kids if he could.
>
> He'd sell his soul to get ahead.